# Verificar se um valor corresponde a um valor em um array

Tags: array, lua

Como verificar se um dado valor corresponde a outro presente num array? Ex:

```
array1 ={nome = "Fulano", idade = 15}
print(array1[idade].nome)
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer checar? e dar um exemplo do que quer dizer com array dentro de array.

Comment: Acho que me expressei errado, mas é o que o exemplo diz.
A array tem 2 campos, e quero checar um campo da array pelo outro, se usar o nome da array, ou quase isso.

Comment: Ok, pode editar a pergunta no botão "editar" em baixo.

Comment: devia usar aspas aqui: `print(array1[idade]`, ou seja `print(array1["idade"]` mas depois não percebo o que quer fazer com `.nome`. Quer verificar se `array1["idade"]` é um objeto com propriedade `nome`?

Comment: Quero pegar o valor "nome" da array de quem possui "idade" igual a 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver isso, é buscando em todos a idade equivalente e só utilizar os nomes que baterem com a idade!

Ex:

```
array1 = {
    {nome = "Paulo", idade = 13},
    {nome = "Fernando", idade = 27},
    {nome = "Fulano", idade = 15},
    {nome = "Rebeca", idade = 15}
}

for i,k in ipairs(array1) do
    if k.idade == 15 then
        print (k.nome) --Ou o que você quiser fazer com o nome
    end
end
```

O resultado desse código irá imprimir Fulano e Rebeca (Que possuem 15 anos).

Comment: Gammeth, perfeito, obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielSales Evite usar os comentários para agradecer, se uma resposta lhe for útil, marque o botão aceito (O V cinza perto da resposta) para que fique verde.